# Insignificant x, but significant x squared

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interpretation, quadratic-form

I have estimated the following model to capture increasing/decreasing marginal effect of $x$ on $y$. :

$y=\alpha + \beta_1x+ \beta_2x^2 +e$

where $\beta_1$ is statistically insignificant, but $\beta_2$ is statistically significant.

1. What's the implication of these statistical significance and insignificance in terms of interpreting the coefficients?
2. Can I still meaninfully calculate the turning point of $x$ by using the formula $x*=\frac{\beta_1}{2\beta_2}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After including the squared term, the effect of $x$, is the effect of $x$ when $x$ is 0. This can easily be a gross extrapolation. You can get around that by first centering $x$ at some meaningful value within the range of the data.

Anyhow, the significance of the main effect does not change the interpretation, so you can do with that result what you want.

Comment: do you mean that $\beta_1$ being insignificant does not create any problem for calculating x*? Also can I conclude on the curvature even when $\beta_1$ is insignificant but $\beta_2$ is significant?

Comment: Correct, you can calculate the max or min without problems. The curvature is governed by the square term, so the significance of the main effect is irrelevant for that.